# How do I throw an error if cell does not contain specific date to date metrics?

Tags: excel

The current problem that I'm facing is this, I have a cell that contains date in this kind of format: `mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy` what I'm trying to accomplish is if it's not in that specific format to throw an error and make the user enter in the dates specifically.

I've tried IF statements and ISERROR statements but everything that I have tried so far doesn't work or throws a #VALUE/False statements.

I would think the code would be something like:
`=IF(A2 = "mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy", "Yes", "No")`
It gives me a False when the `A2` is, 03/01/2019 - 03/31/2019

What I want to result to be is, if the cell does not have, "mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy" format to throw an error stating, 'Please enter the dates as follows: mm/dd/yyyy - mm/dd/yyyy' 
If the cell matches the specific format then continue forward.

Any help would be great with this and much appreciated!
Thanks in advance,

-Maykid

Comment: Considering the string is just a string, with no inherent or pre-defined formatting, you  could verify that certain characters are present in certain location, e.g., If(And(right(left(cell,19),1)="/",right(left(cell,12),1)="-"),True,False)... using the later characters only in example, which if those aren't in the correct place, would indicate something screwed up earlier

Comment: You can use Data Validation with a custom formula, but I believe the complexity of the custom formula will need to exceed the 255 character limit.

Comment: Building on my first comment, I would say the bigger issue, since you have multiple dates in your string, is to verify that have months/days in the correct location... 01/01 is january first, but whcih 01 is january?  12/31 versus 31/12 is pretty simple, but there're still 12 days in any month which could be problematic

Answer (score 0):

This is far from bulletproof, but you could try something like:

```
=SEARCH("??/??/????*??/??/????",A1)
```

Obviously, this does not confirm that the characters are numbers, or even that they are the correct numbers for dates; and there's plenty of ways to enter totally invalid data.

If you require better fidelity to the format, as well as verifying that m, d and y are in the proper ranges, a VBA solution would be preferable.